# Creating a new variable with the average of categories of another variable

Tags: python, replace

I have data of houses sold in different locations. There are a variable "zipcode" and a variable "price". I have to predict for every object the average price for the relative zipcode.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"zipcode":[100, 100, 101, 101], "price":[500, 600, 800, 1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I create a Series with the average price for every zipcode:

```
zipcode_mprice = df.groupby(["zipcode"])["price"].mean()
zipcode_mprice
```

How can I have to create a new variable df["pred_price"] that gives me the average price of the relative zipcode?
It was told me to use the function replace().

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually merge the result with the dataframe:

```
df = df.merge(zipcode_mprice, on= "zipcode" )
df.columns = ["zipcode","price","mean_zipcode"]
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!